# Renaming a structure in MATLAB using an existing string

Tags: string, matlab, data-structures, struct

I have a structure in MATLAB called dat. I want to rename dat as an existing string.

```
Existing_str='NewName'
$(Existing_str)=dat
```

This fails as I don't think MATLAB lets me use the dollar sign in this way. The code below creates a copy of dat literally called Existing_str and destroys the Existing_str in the process.

```
Existing_str=dat
```

While the code below generates a collosal empty structure which clearly is not a copy!

```
eval(Existing_str)=dat
```

In the task I am actually trying to perform I don't know the name of the existing_str in advance so that is not a solution.

Comment: You may want to tell us what the actual task is; there is rarely a good reason to rename a variable like this and if you are using a lot of `eval` it is likely that you are making more work for yourself in the future.

Comment: @nkjt I'm picking out the data I need from a load of netcdf files and sticking them into various arrays in a structure called dat. I then want to rename the structure to prevent overwrites when I load the next lot of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there with your `eval'.  What you want is:

```
eval([Existing_str '=dat;']);
```

This works because you're composing a string inside your square brackets.  If you just looked at the resulting string, it would look like `NewName=dat;`  The `eval` command simply tells Matlab to evaluate the string as if you typed it into the command line.

Comment: Although this does answer the question, I don't think it is good to teach beginners about `eval`. The real question is why you would want to rename a variable, there are usually better ways to achieve the same result. You could do for example `s.(name) = dat`, where `s` is a `struct`.

Comment: @BasSwinckels I'm trying to rename a struct. I don't think this is a variable though I could be wrong about that. I'm doing this because I'm going to be generating multiple structs which in the initial instance are called dat and I want to save the original.

Comment: Please don't do that. The use of eval is *in most cases* an indication of bad code. The use for renaming variables can usually be avoided by choosing the right data structure. You might be able to use a cell array or a struct to save your information.

Comment: @BasSwinckels I'm picking out the data I need from a load of netcdf files and sticking them into various arrays in a structure called dat. I then want to rename the structure to prevent overwrites when I load the next lot of data. I suppose I could stick the 'dat' struct into a another struct (say 'all_dat') but then I still need to rename the dat struct otherwise the next time I load data into all_dat then it will overwrite.

Comment: Well, just stick your structure it in a cell array or other struct, no need to save it in variable.

Comment: @BasSwinckels Sorry that doesn't make sense. Did you see my comment before the edit? I had not intended to post it in the first instance. As it stands your suggestion does not help me.

Comment: Also the good old way: `backupDAT = dat ; clear dat`. This will essentially rename `dat` into `backupDAT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic field naming (Bas's suggestion), and avoid `eval`:

For example, if you have just loaded a structure `dat` from a file `'somefile.ext'` with some custom parsing function:

```
filename = 'somefile.ext'; % presume you actually have a list of files from dir or ls
dat = yourfunction(filename);
[~, name, ~] = fileparts(filename);
alldat.(name)=dat;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
alldat.somefile = dat;
```

Except that we've just automatically taken the name from the filename (in this case just by stripping off the path/extension, but you could do other things depending on the pattern of the filename).

The bonus of this is that you can then, say, with a structure that has fields `alldat.file1, alldata.file2, alldat.file3`, all of which have a subfield, say, `size` do things like this:

```
names = fieldnames(alldat)
for n = 1:length(names)
    alldat.(names{n}).mean = mean(alldata.(names{n}).size);
end
```

Every sub-structure now has a field, `mean`, which contains the mean of the data.  If you had a bunch of different named structures you would need to `eval` everything you wanted to do to them collectively, and the code becomes difficult to read and maintain.

The other option is a cell array.  Here's an easy trick:

```
dat = % whatever you do to make this structure
alldat{end+1} = dat;
```

This just appends the new `dat` onto the end of an existing cell array.  `{end+1}` ensures it doesn't overwrite existing data.

Comment: This is exactly why I ask questions in a really basic way. I've read it several times and only kind of understand what it means though I'm pretty sure it doesn't relate to what I am doing or help me at all. I can't ask detailed questions well enough to get a good answer and am left confused by the responses.

Comment: It looks like you think I am just reading in files I am not. I am picking out specific chracteristics (e.g. the maximum of an array here, the value of a variable there) and putting them each of these values into a vector array of these values (e.g. the max of a variable called RH goes into dat.RH_max) the original filenames are not interesting to me they are of the form 'commonstring'+str2num(number).

I am certain that I have not expressed this clearly enough for you to be able to do anything useful with it but I wanted to try to demonstrate why this answer doesn't help me.